# Printing on three remote terminals in TCP/IP echo server

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, centos

I have an echo server and three clients, what I need is that each client can send data to the server, and that each data be printed in three different terminal in the server.

I wonder if this is possible and what additional features I need to use to do so. I just need an orientation about what elements I can use do get what I want.

I'm working with C language, and four computers with CentOS. Here is the code of my two programs (I omite the error handling code):

Client program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int clientSocket,remotePort,status=0;
  struct sockaddr_in ServerName={0};
  char buffer[256]="";
  char *remoteHost=NULL;
  remoteHost=argv[1];
  remotePort=atoi(argv[2]);
  clientSocket= socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
  ServerName.sin_family=AF_INET;
  ServerName.sin_port=htons(remotePort);
  ServerName.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr=(remoteHost);
  status=connect(clientSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&ServerName,sizeof(ServerName));
  while(strcmp(buffer,"exit"))
  {
    scanf("%s",buffer);
    write(clientSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    read(clientSocket,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
  }
}
```

Server program:

```
#define BACK_LOG 5
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int serverSocket=0,status=0,clientSocket=0,longitud=0,port;
  char buffer[256]="";
  struct sockaddr_in serverName,clientName;
  buffer[0]='\0';
  port=atoi(argv[1]);
  serverSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  serverName.sin_family=AF_INET;
  serverName.sin_port=htons(port);
  serverName.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  status=bind(serverSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&serverName, sizeof(serverName));
  status=listen(serverSocket,BACK_LOG);
  int clientLength = sizeof(clientName);
  clientSocket=accept(serverSocket,(struct sockaddr *)&clientName, &clientLength);
  while(read(clientSocket,buffer,sizeof(buffer))!=0)
  {
    longitud=strlen(buffer);
    printf("%s %i\n",buffer,strlen(buffer));
    write(clientSocket,buffer,longitud);
    strncpy(buffer,buffer,longitud+1);
  }
  close(serverSocket);
}
```

Comment: Look up the `select` system call.

Comment: Thank's, I have found two options: using `select` and using `threads` with `pthread`, is a good way to handle multiple connections in my echo server.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two options: using select and using threads with pthread, is a good way to handle multiple connections in my echo server. – Richard